# calculate average of a specific column in codeigniter select query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to calculate average of a specific column, for eg. rating column for that i am writing the following query but it is giving me syntax error in the query, Please help to solve my problem.

```
$this->db->select('*, AVG(`rating`) As avg_r');
```

Comment: show us the error then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('id, name, email, AVG(rating) as avg_r');
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter by default protect field you can disable the protection by passing one extra second parameter.

```
$this->db->select('*, AVG(`rating`) As avg_r',FALSE);
```

as $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks

For More info you can refer Active record documentation
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html